# Adjust Eclipse Methods Menu Size

Tags: eclipse, methods, contextmenu

I don't know how I accidentally did this but the methods menu in my Eclipse window is too big and I want to resize it back. The menu I'm talking about is the one that pops up when you type a "." after an object and it brings down a list of methods you can use on it. I must have accidentally dragged the menu to large and now I can't drag it back. Does anyone know the name of this menu? Or better yet, how I can resize it back to normal?

Comment: Nevermind about this, I figured it out myself. :)

Comment: Care to explain it for other folks' benefit?

Comment: Well I'm not sure exactly how I fixed it but I was clicking something randomly and it got the menu to collapse to a very small size. I then moved my cursor to the bottom right corner of this menu and clicked to expand it out back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This menu can be re-sized like a classic window by putting the mouse pointer at the bottom right of the menu and dragging the mouse to expand or reduce it.

Comment: I though that it was that simple, but the every time I click the bottom right corner to drag it, it just gets bigger. Perhaps it's because I'm using KDE or Eclipse doesn't like the interface it's in.  Either way, some clicking around finally got it work. :)